# SwiftUI and Core Data: determine a value by comparing multiple fetches

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

Entities:  TestGroup<-->>ActionItem<-->>TestPoint

I'm trying to determine the "status" of an entity based on TestPoint attribute passOrFail, which has three possible strings.

The only way I could keep the ActionItem consistent with TestPoint was to run three new fetchRequests in a master view that uses the following row view in a list:

```
struct ActionItemsListCellView: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

  @ObservedObject var actionItem: ActionItem

  var fetchPass: FetchRequest<TestPoint>
  var fetchFail: FetchRequest<TestPoint>
  var fetchNotTested: FetchRequest<TestPoint>

  init(actionItem: ActionItem) {
    self.actionItem = actionItem
    self.fetchPass = FetchRequest(entity: TestPoint.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "belongsToActionItem == %@ && passOrFail == %@", actionItem, "Pass"))
    self.fetchFail = FetchRequest(entity: TestPoint.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "belongsToActionItem == %@ && passOrFail == %@", actionItem, "Fail"))
    self.fetchNotTested = FetchRequest(entity: TestPoint.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "belongsToActionItem == %@ && passOrFail == %@", actionItem, "Not Tested"))
  }

  var fetchedPass: FetchedResults<TestPoint> {fetchPass.wrappedValue}
  var fetchedFail: FetchedResults<TestPoint> {fetchFail.wrappedValue}
  var fetchedNotTested: FetchedResults<TestPoint> {fetchNotTested.wrappedValue}

  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: TestPointListView(actionItem: actionItem)) {
      VStack {
        Text(actionItem.wrappedName)
        Text("\(fetchedPass.count)")
        Text("\(fetchedFail.count)")
        Text("\(fetchedNotTested.count)")
      }.background(self.fetchedFail.count == "Fail" ? Color.red : nil)
    }
  }
}
```

Here's rows for the detail view, which is just a list of test points

```
struct TestPointListCellView: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

  @ObservedObject var testPoint: TestPoint

  @State private var selection = 0
  let statusChoices = ["Pass", "Not Tested", "Fail"]

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(testPoint.wrappedName)

      if testPoint.timeStamp != nil {
        Text("\(testPoint.timeStamp!, formatter: self.dateFormatter)")
      }

      Picker(selection: $selection, label:
        Text("Status:")){
          ForEach(0 ..< statusChoices.count) { index in
            Text(self.statusChoices[index])
          }
      }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

      Section{
        Button("Save") {
          self.testPoint.passOrFail = self.statusChoices[self.selection]
          self.testPoint.timeStamp = Date()
          do {
            try self.moc.save()
          } catch {
            print(error)
          }
        }
      }.padding()

    }.padding()
      .onAppear{
      self.selection = self.statusChoices.firstIndex(of: self.testPoint.passOrFail!)!
    }
  }
}
```

The .background works with a ternary, but not a full if statement that I need to set the correct color.

How can I set the background color of a VStack within an action item cell based on the following:
If any test points are "Not Tested": yellow
If no "Not Tested" test points:  if any test points are "Fail": red
If all test points are "Pass": green

I have to do this again with the parent to ActionItem.  Will I have to do fetches of fetches to get the test point values?  There has to be a better way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the relationships and inheritance would allow changes to be detected when the parent was an @ObservedObject.  But that didn't hold up.

I had to do a fetch for all test points on all the views.  I then wrote a function that was called with .background to set the desired color.